# What is going on with this `git clone` statement?

Tags: git, github

I came across a tutorial that asked for the following statement to be executed.

```
git clone -b 00 git@github.com:gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app.git
```

However, it just ends in a fatal error. Then I tried, replacing the email address with my own... And I got the following message.

> ssh: connect to host gmail.com port 22: Network is unreachable fatal:
> Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I am trying to discover what the above statement is doing exactly. How can I get around the problem?

### Update

Although, I can regularly clone the repository using the full github address with `git clone https://...`, I would still like to use and understand the original statement above.

Comment: `git@github.com` mean user ID "git" of site "github.com", not an email address. If you put gmail.com there then it means you are asking to retrieve source code from gmail.com

Comment: @M.M Yes, that is what I assumed. The gmail address that I provided is actually the ID that I use to login to github.... Or do I have to use something like `myusername@github.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EliKor explained the following in his answer.

> The -b 00 option for git clone is telling to point the HEAD of your
> clone of the repository to the branch specified by the following name.
> In this case the branch name is 00. See documentation on git clone -b
> here. The git@github.com:gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app.git that
> follows is the location of the repository that you want to clone. It
> is in the format [user]@[host]:[directory_location], which is what
> you'll see for utilities like scp. Github allows you to clone
> repositories using the SSH protocol, in which you set up an SSH key on
> your machine and share the public key with github to be used to
> authenticate you.

So, it is now quite apparent that to use the `git clone` statement mentioned in the question above, one would have to set up an SSH key and connect to GitHub using that. For details on how to do that, please follow the [link](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) provided by @EliKor.

However, it appears that the benefit in doing that is simply the following, as mentioned by the [documentation](http://Using%20the%20SSH%20protocol,%20you%20can%20connect%20and%20authenticate%20to%20remote%20servers%20and%20services.%20With%20SSH%20keys,%20you%20can%20connect%20to%20GitHub%20without%20supplying%20your%20username%20or%20password%20at%20each%20visit.).

> Using the SSH protocol, you can connect and authenticate to remote
> servers and services. With SSH keys, you can connect to GitHub without
> supplying your username or password at each visit.

So, for those of you who are happy to connect regularly using your username and password, simply use the following git clone statement instead. No need for the extra headache of setting up an SSH with GitHub.

```
git clone -b 00 https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app.git
```

It works like a beauty!

Answer (score 5):

The `-b 00` option for `git clone` is telling to point the HEAD of your clone of the repository to the branch specified by the following name. In this case the branch name is `00`. See documentation on `git clone -b` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--bltnamegt). The `git@github.com:gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app.git` that follows is the location of the repository that you want to clone. It is in the format [user]@[host]:[directory_location], which is what you'll see for utilities like [scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp). Github allows you to clone repositories using the SSH protocol, in which you set up an SSH key on your machine and share the public key with github to be used to authenticate you. See more details on this [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh). To get this working I would follow along with the instructions from the previous link and set up your own ssh key with Github.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for that. However, can you then tell me what the difference is between going through all the hassle of setting up an SSH key versus simply just doing `git clone https://github.com/...` using the full github repo address. If I just simply clone it, it works... So why would it be better to go via the ssh route?

Comment: @Grateful: The main reason to use ssh instead of https is that some sites don't support https. The main reason to use https instead of ssh is that some sites don't support ssh. GitHub support both, so that drops you down from "main reason" to "secondary reasons".